# Google Maps JS API v3 - UrlAuthentication

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Last few days I was testing Google Maps JS Api on localhost without any issues. From today I started getting error

> UrlAuthenticationCommonError: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#errorcodes

Frankly this error is not even described on that URL. My guess was something was up with Url Authentication (I know, I am genius). I included localhost in allowed referrers. Error was still here.

Than I uploaded site on azure. Included url in allowed referrer and still nothing. Same error again and again.

Unfortunately google was not very helpful.

Just in case this is code. Direct copy/past from demo page. Same exact code was working yesterday but not today

```
function  init(params) {

var mapOPtions = {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom:8
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOPtions)
}




<html>
<head>
    <title>Proto Wars</title>
    <style>
        html, body, #map { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC-MmP-PKBmtLOobOynyJQvlBpYzp84Tr0">
</script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>


        <div id="map" style="background-color: #000"></div>
</body>
```